# Beautifulsoup web-scraping website with drop down menu

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, get

I am trying to scrape a site that has a drop down menu where the user can select the year for the data to display.  However, I seem to be stuck in my implementation of this.

Here is the website URL: https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/masters-tournament/past-results.html

This is for a personal project to scrape golf data for each major tournament for each year.  I know how to pull the desired stats once the year has been selected.

Here is an example of the websites html for the drop down menu

```html
<select name="year" id="pastResultsYearSelector" class="hasCustomSelect"
style="-webkit-appearance: menulist-button; width: 180px; position: absolute;
opacity: 0; height: 42px; font-size: 18px;">
            <option value="2019" selected="selected">2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
headers = {
    'user-agent': 
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'
    }

data = {
    'name':'2019', 'id':'pastResultYearSelector', 'class':'hasCustomSelect',
    'style':'-webkit-appearance: menulist-button; width: 180px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 42px; font-size: 18px;'
    }

url = "https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/masters-tournament/past-results.html"

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=20)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

However my request seems to be invalid, as I get a response saying the requested page was not found.

Comment: If the page uses Ajax then the data is loaded after page load. You can use the developer tools on a browser to double check this.

Comment: Consider something like selenium.

Comment: baseURL: "/content/pgatour/tournaments/masters-tournament/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear." have you seen this? I think you are posting to wrong url.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you can use the following url construct which the page does to update content by year

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/tournaments/masters-tournament/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear.{}.html'.format(2017))

soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
```

You will want to do some dataframe tifying but you could use pandas to grab the handle the table

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/tournaments/masters-tournament/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear.{}.html'.format(2017))
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table')))[0]
```